# Show that there is exactly one linear map $ \Phi: \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3} $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, determinant

> In the real vector space $ \mathbb{R}^{3} $ the following vectors are given:
>   $ v_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{c}{-2} \\ {-2} \\ {1}\end{array}\right), \quad v_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{c}{0} \\ {-1} \\ {-2}\end{array}\right), \quad v_{3}=\left(\begin{array}{c}{1} \\ {1} \\ {1}\end{array}\right) \quad $ and $ \quad w_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{c}{-1} \\ {-2} \\ {3}\end{array}\right), \quad w_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{c}{1} \\ {-1} \\ {0}\end{array}\right), \quad w_{3}=\left(\begin{array}{c}{0} \\ {1} \\ {-1}\end{array}\right) $
>
> i) Show that there is exactly one linear map $ \Phi: \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3} $ with $ \Phi\left(v_{i}\right)=w_{i} $ for $i \in\{1,2,3\}$.
>
> ii) Determine $\operatorname{ker}(\Phi), $ im$ (\Phi) $ and their dimensions.
>
> iii) Determine $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3} $ with $ \Phi_{A}=\Phi $.
>
> iv) Determine $det(\Phi)$.

How can I show that there is *exactly* one linear map? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A linear map is uniquely specified by its behaviour on a basis. so, maybe check that the $v_k$ form a basis?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it sufficient to show that the vectors are linearly independent by calculating the determinant and using its result to express whether the vectors are linearly independent or dependent?

Comment: That will work since you have 3 points in 3 space

Comment: Could you also give me a hint on how to determine the $ker(\Phi)$ and $im(\Phi)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent so they form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. In particular, every vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ can be expressed uniquely as 
$$
x = av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3
$$
for some constants $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$. As $\Phi$ must be linear, we may define $\Phi$ uniquely as
$$
\Phi(x) = \Phi(av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3) = a\Phi(v_1) + b\Phi(v_2) + c\Phi(v_3) = aw_1 + bw_2 + cw_3
$$
for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$. It is now evident that $\mathrm{im}(\Phi)=\mathrm{span}\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$. Note, however, that the vectors $w_1,w_2,w_3$ are *not* linearly independent as 
$$w_1 +w_2+3w_3 = 0. \tag{$\ast$}
$$ In particular, we see that $w_1$ is in the span of $w_2$ and $w_3$ and that $w_2$ and $w_3$ are linearly independent. We may conclude that 
$$
\mathrm{im}(\Phi) = \mathrm{span}\{w_2,w_3\} = \left\{aw_2+bw_3\,\middle|\,a,b\in\mathbb{R}\right\}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a\\b-a\\-b\end{pmatrix}\,\middle|\,a,b\in\mathbb{R}\right\}
$$
and that $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{im}(\Phi))=2$. By the rank-nullity theorem, we may conclude that $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ker}(\Phi)) = 3-\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{im}(\Phi)) = 1$. To find the kernel of $\Phi$, note from ($\ast$) that $\Phi(v_1+v_2+3v_3)=0$, and thus 
$$
\mathrm{ker}(\Phi) = \mathrm{span}\{v_1+v_2+3v_3\} = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}a\\0\\2a\end{pmatrix}\,\middle|\, a\in\mathbb{R}\right\}.
$$

I'll leave it to you to determine the matrix form of $\Phi$. However, as $\Phi$ does not have trivial kernel, its matrix form $A$ is not invertible, so we can immediately conclude that $\mathrm{det}(A)=0$.

---

Edit: A hint for finding the matrix $A$.

Let $V$ and $W$ denote the matrices whose columns are $v_1,v_2,v_3$ and $w_1,w_2,w_3$ respectively. It is the case that 
$$
V\begin{pmatrix} a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix} = av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3
$$
and that 
$$
W\begin{pmatrix} a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix} = aw_1 + bw_2 + cw_3.
$$
hold for each $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$. You need to find a matrix $A$ such that 
$$
A(av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3) = aw_1 + bw_2 + cw_3.
$$
How can you find $A$ from $V$ and $W$?

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Doesn't the matrix form of $\Phi$ simply consist of the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_3$ as a matrix? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: See my edit for a hint.

Comment: I appreciate your hint but I am still not entirely sure how to continue... I am relatively new to this.

Comment: As every vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be uniquely expressed as $av_1+bv_2+cv+3$ for some values $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$, this means that the matrix $V$ is invertible. How can you combine $V^{-1}$ and $W$ to make $A$?